# Safari downloads dialog very slow

Tags: safari

I recently upgraded to 10.13 High Sierra, and one thing I noticed almost immediately was that the downloads dialog in Safari was incredibly slow. When I click the icon next to the address bar which should show the recent downloads, it takes about 5 seconds to show, during which the browser is unresponsive. After clicking somewhere else to dismiss the recent downloads box, the browser is totally unresponsive for another three seconds or so. In addition to this, when I click a link to start downloading something, the browser is unresponsive for a few seconds, and also upon finishing a download there are a few seconds of unresponsiveness.

Note that this is *not* about the speed of the downloads themselves. I don't have any browser extensions installed (I used to have the Zotero extension installed, but that broke after upgrading to 10.13).

Does anyone know of a solution to this? I access downloads a lot (for academic papers), and this is driving me mental.

Comment: what is your Safari version

Comment: I have Safari version 12.0.

Comment: Let's try to isolate possible causes first. Can you create a new user on your Mac and try it in the new account? Does the problem occur there as well?

Comment: that pesky Zotero could be still there, but broken as you say. Lets look for it in Terminal with `mdfind zotero`

Comment: @nohillside Well, it seemed like deleting Library/Safari did the trick. It didn't delete my history though (who knows where that is stored). I also found out that while you can drag folders of bookmarks *out* of Safari to the desktop, you cannot drag them back *in* to Safari (it works with individual bookmarks, but not folders). Yay for consistency... At any rate, this did fix the problem, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If clearing history etc from within Safari doesn't help, try the following

- Export all bookmarks
- Quit Safari
- Open Terminal and run `cd ~/Library && rm -r Safari`
- Restart Safari
- Import bookmarks

Comment: Hi @nohillside♦, thanks for your help. This did fix the problem for a day or so, but now I find the downloads dialog lagging out again, it's back up to 2/3 second pauses on any interaction with it.

Comment: @Joppy bad news indeed. Any extensions in Safari? Does it happen with any sites or just some. Does it change if you switch sites/close tabs while the download is going on?

Comment: No, it lags pretty consistently regardless of the site, size of the download, etc. As I said before, it only lags when "interacting" with the download, being starting it, finishing it, or opening/closing the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

First lets clean it up.

Exit the Preferences dialog and click on Develop in the Safari menu. Go ahead and click on Empty Caches. Once the cache is empty, click again on Develop and choose Disable Extensions.

Finally, click on Safari and instead of Preferences like we chose above, click on Clear History.

I think you have some broken parts of the Zotero still active. If I understand its function, it will use the Download function for its work.

Try to find it with `mdfind zotero` in Terminal

Comment: What does "Reset Safari" mean?

Comment: sorry, that would mean to reinstall the OS X.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS will not help if the problem is with the user settings in `~/Library`. If you assume an installation issue, reinstalling Safari 12 (which is a separate download for 10.13 anyway) would be enough.

Comment: @nohillside I agree with you, and think it is some left over from the Zotero extension that broke.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried using mdfind zotero, but it didn't return anything Safari-related.

Comment: @Joppy I hope you saved your bookmarks (Exported them) do not want to loose those. So the Terminal did not show any `zotero` that is strange. I have it from just visiting a zotero web site.